# Dividing an array

Tags: c, arrays

:D

My problem is I have to divide a bigger array into smaller fixed size arrays. I'm just wondering what is the best method for dividing an array. I saw a question here and derived a method out of it. The number of array is changing. Indices is the array where i'm pointing the pointers.

```
int *ptr[num];//array of pointers
ptr[0] = indices;//points the first pointer in the first element of the array

for (y = 1; y <= num; y++) {
    ptr[y] = ptr[y-1] + Size;//points the next pointer to it's position.
}
```

What I wanted to ask is my method correct? And if there is alternative solutions for dividing arrays. I'm going to pass the small arrays by the way.

Comment: You can not divide array into two smaller part, because array size is fixed.

Comment: I'm not dividing them literally. I'm just pointing pointers into the array.

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to avoid loops where the result of each iteration depends on the previous iteration.

```
int *ptr[num];//array of pointers
ptr[0] = indices;//points the first pointer in the first element of the array

for (y = 1; y < num; y++) {
    ptr[y] = ptr[0] + y*Size;//points the next pointer to it's position.
}
```

The reason for this is that if anyone changes the starting value of `y` then the loop is broken. For instance if you decided that `ptr[1]` will never be used you could start `y` at 2. This would appear to be correct except that `ptr[2]` will get assigned to `ptr[1]` which never got initialized.

For such a simple loop what you are doing is fine.

You don't mention how you are planning to use these pointers but if it is something like:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < num; ++ii)
   myFunction(ptr[ii]);
```

Then it may be simpler to just use 'indicies' directly:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < num; ++ii)
   myFunction(indicies + ii*Size);
```

or this way:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < num; ++ii)
   myFunction(indicies[ii*Size]);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what issues you are having passing the pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Some minor fixes use smaller than rather than smaller than or equal + you have to calculate size,

```
int *ptr[num];//array of pointers
ptr[0] = indices;//points the first pointer in the first element of the array

for (y = 1; y < num; y++) {
    ptr[y] = ptr[y-1] + Size;//points the next pointer to it's position.
}
```

Now this method will not actually divide the array, but will create pointers to places inside the array. you cannot delete the new divided sub-arrays individually. You can only delete the bigger array. This solution has better performance than copying the bigger array to smaller sub-arrays.

Comment: Ok. Yeah i'm aware that i'm pointing it to the places inside the array. So if I'm going to pass this pointers, will I actually get array with size "Size"? What do you mean I have to calculate the size?

Comment: you have either calculate size or num, num = size of big array/Size or Size = size of big array/num. after that you will get arrays of size Size because of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Oh sorry. I actually did that. This is a snippet from my code. Thanks! Your a big help. :D